# CUDA equivalent of pragma omp task

Tags: multithreading, cuda, openmp

I am working on a problem where work between each thread may varies drastically, where, for example, a thread may this time handle 1000000 element, but another thread may only handle 1 or 2 element. So I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459220/splitting-openmp-threads-on-unbalanced-tree) where the answer solve the unbalanced workload by using openmp task on CPU, so my question is can I achieve the same on CUDA ?

In case you want more context:
The problem I'm trying to solve is, I have a **n** tuple, each has a starting point, an ending point and a value.

```
(0, 3, 1), (3, 6, 2), (6, 10, 3), ...
```

So for each tuple I want to write the value to every position between starting point and ending point of another empty array.

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...
```

It is guaranteed that there is no start/ ending overlap.

My current approach is a thread for each tuple, but the starting and ending can vary a lot so the imbalanced workload between threads might cause a bottleneck for the program, though rare, but it may very well be.

Comment: Your problem sound like literally the worst possible use case for CUDA imaginable. There is no magical load balance facility in CUDA. If you need one, you will have to write it yourself. Perhaps start by stop thinking that CUDA is multithreading, because it really isn't

Comment: Well :( Such a shame though. So if I need one, can you show me how can I get started ? (Just for learning purpose, as you can see) Thank you for helping me though \(^_^)/

Comment: There is no direct equivalent because GPUs are not made to execute different tasks in different threads. Actually, GPU threads are totally different from CPU threads. Nvidia GPUs are based on the *SIMT model* that does not directly match with your needs. There might be a way to efficiently do that with CUDA, but not without redesigning deeply the algorithm. Besides this, the lack of parallelism is likely a fondamental limitation to use GPUs efficiently.

Comment: Problems written in english are rarely precise enough for a good delivery, in my opinion.  However based on what I read here, it should be possible to get the work done while giving each thread the same amount of work to do. Simply spin up enough threads for the total number of entries in all the start/finish arrays.  Then each thread is responsible for populating exactly one value.  This doesn't address overlap of start/end points between separate number populations, but your description doesn't address that either.  So I think it's better to provide an exact algorithm.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Sorry for the inconvenience. I have update the problems, care to take another look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common thread strategy I can think of in CUDA is to assign one thread per output point, and then have each thread do the work necessary to populate its output point.

For your stated objective (have each thread do roughly equal work) this is a useful strategy.

I will suggest using thrust for this.  The basic idea is to:

1. determine the necessary size of the output based on the input
2. spin up a set of threads equal to the output size, where each thread determines its "insert index" in the output array by using a vectorized binary search on the input
3. with the insert index, insert the appropriate value in the output array.

I have used your data, the only change is that I changed the insert values from 1,2,3 to 5,2,7:

```
$ cat t1871.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/binary_search.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

typedef thrust::tuple<int,int,int> mt;

// returns selected item from tuple
struct my_cpy_functor1
{
  __host__ __device__ int operator()(mt d){ return thrust::get<1>(d); }
};
struct my_cpy_functor2
{
  __host__ __device__ int operator()(mt d){ return thrust::get<2>(d); }
};

int main(){

  mt my_data[] = {{0, 3, 5}, {3, 6, 2}, {6, 10, 7}};
  int ds = sizeof(my_data)/sizeof(my_data[0]); // determine data size
  int os = thrust::get<1>(my_data[ds-1]) - thrust::get<0>(my_data[0]); // and output size
  thrust::device_vector<mt> d_data(my_data, my_data+ds);  // transfer data to device
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_idx(ds+1); // create index array for searching of insertion points
  thrust::transform(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), d_idx.begin()+1, my_cpy_functor1()); // set index array
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_ins(os);  // create array to hold insertion points
  thrust::upper_bound(d_idx.begin(), d_idx.end(), thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), thrust::counting_iterator<int>(os), d_ins.begin()); // identify insertion points
  thrust::transform(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_data.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_ins.begin(), _1 -1)), thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d_data.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(d_ins.end(), _1 -1)), d_ins.begin(), my_cpy_functor2()); // insert
  thrust::copy(d_ins.begin(), d_ins.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}


$ nvcc -o t1871 t1871.cu -std=c++14
$ ./t1871
5,5,5,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,
$
```

Comment: So the idea is you trade a small computation time by using the upper bound for a more balanced workload between thread. Thank you very much sir \(^_^)/